# ember.js application does not update hashtag part of URI with NGINX server

Tags: nginx, ember.js

I have an ember.js application I developped on my local machine. I use a restify/node.js server to make it available locally.

When I navigate in my application, the address bar changes like this:

**Example 1**

```
1. http://dev.server:3000/application/index.html#about
2. http://dev.server:3000/application/index.html#/items
3. http://dev.server:3000/application/index.html#/items/1
4. http://dev.server:3000/application/index.html#/items/2
```

I try now to deploy it on a remote test server which runs nginx.

Although everything works well locally, I can navigate into my web application but the part of the URI that is after the hashtag is not updated.

In any browser: `http://test.server/application/index.html` is always displayed in my address bar. For the same sequence of clicks as in **Exemple 1**, I always have:

```
1. http://web.redirection/application/index.html
2. http://web.redirection/application/index.html
3. http://web.redirection/application/index.html
4. http://web.redirection/application/index.html
```

Moreover, if I directly enter a complete URI `http://web.redirection/application/index.html#/items/1` the browser will only display the content that is at `http://test.server/application/index.html` (which is definitely not the expected behaviour).

I suppose this come from my NGINX configuration since the application works perfectly on a local restify server.

NGINX configuration for this server is:

test.server.conf (which is symlinked into /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.server.conf)

```
    server {
        server_name test.server web.redirection;

        root /usr/share/nginx/test;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location ~ \.csv$ {    
            alias /usr/share/nginx/test/$uri;
        }
    }
```

nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Just to be sure that there were no missing files on my test server: I ran a restify/node server (like on my dev machine) and *everything works fine* when I connect to this server (!). Both nginx and restify servers points to the same files.

**EDIT 2**

I discovered that my problem happens when I use a web redirection.
If I use an address like `http://test.server/application/index.html` everything works fine
If I use `http://web.redirection/application/index.html` it does not work.

So this is my nginx conf that is not correctly redirecting web.redirection URI to test.server or something like that.

Does someone has an idea ? What do I miss ? What should I change to make this work ?

**EDIT 3 and solution**

The web redirection I used was an A type DNS record. This does not work. Using a CNAME type DNS record solves the issue.

Comment: can you confirm that all the files needed by your ember app are correctly deployed to `/usr/share/nginx/test`?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this:I made several git clone and the ones that do not work are on the remote server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the DNS redirection from web.redirection to test.server.

It was an A-type record: this does not work.

Using a CNAME-type record that points directly to test.server works.

Answer (score 1):

No, this has nothing to do with nginx, any thing past the `#` is never sent to the server, a javascript code should handle this, I would suggest to use firebug or any inspector to make sure that all your js files are  being loaded, and nothing fails with a 404 error, also check for console errors on the inspector console.

Comment: +1 add LOG_TRANSITIONS: true to your app and see if router is transitioning as you expect when navigating the app. Most likely some resource that was available locally is not there in production.

Comment: Yes it is transitionning as expected. Everything is available in production. To check this, I ran a restify server on the test server that points to the code that is exactly at the same path as the one for the nginx server: everything works fine ! So I really believe (even if I agree that part after # should not be sent to the server) this comes from nginx. May be my rules filter something that shouldn't be ?

Comment: Ok, I apologize because I missed something that I think may cause the issue: I have actually a web redirection as explained in my edit and the problem occurs when I use it (problem disappears when I use the server name)

Comment: Well, after a good night the solution came to me: the problem was with the web redirection. Using an A record type prevents the part after the # to be updated. **Using a CNAME recort type for web redirection solves the problem**. I am not experienced with this difference and sorry that I was not aware the difference was so important.